# Evaluate a string as condition and apply on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file with many conditions listed. And a pandas dataframe. My conditions are like `Pat_BirthYear >= 2000` or like `Akr1 != 1 | Akr2 != 1`. I want to evaluate this and apply for each row in my dataframe and get the rows back which match this conditions. The variables are columns in my dataframe, along some other columns. I read the excel file with `pd.read_excel()` and get the `Pat_BirthYear >= 2000` as a string.
But now i have no clue what to do. Something like `eval` and `df.apply`?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1995,0,1],[2,1996,1,1],[3,2001,0,0]],columns=('ID','Pat_BirthYear','Akr1','Akr2'))

expr='Pat_BirthYear >= 2000'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df1.query(expr)
print (df)
   ID  Pat_BirthYear  Akr1  Akr2
2   3           2001     0     0
```